# SQL (Oracle) - How to force a value in one column to be NULL if data containing specific value is entered in another column in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I'm trying to figure out how you would constrain a certain column in a table to have be set to NULL or a specific string like "N/A" if a specific value is entered in another column.

I'm creating a table for teachers and each teacher has a supervisor ID (i.e. an ID relating to another teacher who is there immediate boss) but I don't want the Head Teacher to be able to have a supervisor. How would I create a constraint or method so that if the value for another column in the table - "teacherRole" is inserted as "Head Teacher", you would be prevented from giving this individual a supervisor ID and it would be set to NULL?

I.e. IF teacherRole = "Head Teacher" SET supervisorID = NULL

Also, I'm using another constraint so that "teacherRole" can only be one of a select number of values such as "PE Teacher" or "Maths Teacher" and want to make sure another constraint would not conflict with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent this you could add a check constraint to the table:

```
alter table mytable
   add constraint mytable_chk1
      check (not (teacherRole = 'Head Teacher' and supervisorID is not NULL));
```

Then if someone tries to insert or update a row such that it validates the constraint they will get an exception raised.

Comment: A bit simpler: `check (teacherrole != 'Head Teacher' or supervisorid is null)`. (Obviously, logically equivalent, but there are fewer logical operations - and it avoids the double negation in "not ... something is not null".) Regardless, +1 as this is obviously the right answer.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks.  I wrote it this way as I thought it maybe easier to follow - obviously a matter of opinion!

Answer (score 0):

apparently I am foolish and nonsensical

Comment: `select case ...` has nothing to do with constraints. "stored procedure" has nothing to do with constraints.